# is there a way to pass two values in an input checkbox to the $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, input, checkbox

I have a bunch of checkboxes on the page and i want to pass two values for each checkbox like this....

```
<input name="class[]" value="first_value" data="second_value" type="checkbox" class="auto"/>
```

any idea how to get `first_value` and `second_value` past to the $_POST in php

any suggestions on how to do this

Comment: just curious why you need to pass two values for a single input. can't you put the two values together as one in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this

```
<input name="class[]" value="CIS 2910C DL:3" type="checkbox" class="auto"/>
```

where you separate the two values by a : or whatever other separator you want.

Then on the $_POST you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in a loop like this

```
$pieces = explode(":", $class);
echo $pieces[0]; // CIS 2910C DL
echo $pieces[1]; // 3
```

so you can pull out both values

Comment: This is the way to do it. Combine with `implode()` and retrieve with `explode()` ...

Comment: The rails equivalent to this is split(). So you'd do `value1, value2 = value.split(':')` where value is "CIS 2910C DL:3".

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly. I'd loop through with jquery and create new hidden inputs with those values and delete the data attr.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<input name="class[second_value][]" value="first_value" type="checkbox" class="auto"/>
```

Then in PHP

```
foreach($_POST['class'] as $first_value=>$tmpArray) {
    foreach($tmpArray as $second_value) {
        echo $first_value.": ".$second_value;
    }
}
```

Odd way of doing it, but its seems like an odd situation you are in anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do this if you use ajax, or if you add a hidden field with an index sequential '[]' buying the checkbox with the value of X in X location hidden